# Can suds (SOAP python library) get only some methods of wsdl file (part of whole API)?

Tags: python, memory-management, soap, wsdl, suds

I am using some SOAP python library - suds:

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Even I used suds with some improvments (slots) - great but still much memory usage!!!

So I have a question:

Is it possible to download only part of wsdl - I need only two metods, but whole API is very big:

> self.client = Client('https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php?wsdl',
>   cache=None)

I tried read it from local file (shorted version of big wsdl):

> self.client = Client(url='file:///home/tomek/pythonScript/service.php?wsdl', location='https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php',
>   cache=None)

but it does't work:

```
suds/bindings/binding.py", line 149, in get_reply
    soapenv.promotePrefixes()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'
```

Please HELP ME!!!